# Internal server error 500 when try to insert huge amount of data?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, iis, laravel-5.1

i had a problem. I try to insert huge amount of data ~400K rows. 
Somewhere in middle of execution - i get error

> "internal server error 500".

Can you help me to solve it? (Laravel 5.1, IIS)

```
public function updateForClients(Request $request) {
    Debugbar::disable();
    if($request->has('sku_list') && $request->has('clients')) {
        DB::disableQueryLog();
        $sku_list = array_map('trim', explode('|', $request->get('sku_list')));
        $clients = array_map('trim', explode('|', $request->get('clients')));
        $text_color_date = Carbon::parse($request->get('text_color_date'));
        $text_color = $request->get('color');
        $sql = [];
        $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        foreach($clients as $client) {
            $sql[$client] = "BEGIN TRANSACTION ";
            $sql[$client] .= "DELETE FROM eltk.dbo.system_products_meta_client WHERE client_id = '" . $client . "' AND sku IN ('". implode("', '", $sku_list) ."') ";
            foreach($sku_list as $sku) {    
                $sql[$client] .= "INSERT INTO eltk.dbo.system_products_meta_client VALUES ('" . $sku . "', '" . $client . "', '" . $text_color . "', '" . $text_color_date . "', '" . $today ."', '" . $today ."') ";
            }
            $sql[$client] .= "COMMIT TRANSACTION GO";
        }
        foreach($sql as $query) {
            DB::statement($query);
        }
        return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('form_success', true)->with('form_message', 'Information saved successfully!');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: checked already max_execution_time in php? http://php.net/manual/de/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Its probably a timeout from either the webserver or from php itself. Start by trying to raise the timeout for php see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Also I'd seriously consider rewriting the above code its very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thats another good hint! Why use raw SQL instead of ORM? They work with transactions very well.

Comment: Another also consider using bulk inserts http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts should make a big difference to your insert time.

Comment: max_execution_time setted to 30 minutes

Comment: Mark Davidson, we use MS SQL, i can't use multiple insert :(